# No true novel Torah?

Tags: torah-study, reincarnation

If Kohelet said there is nothing new under the sun, then can there ever really be a novel Torah? Also, could it be that the Torah we deem as novel is really just dvar Torahs that were conceived in a past gilgul?

Comment: Does it also mean that iPods don't exist? Or were they also developed in a previous gilgul?

Comment: @Double AA The question isn't about existence so much. It's about originality. So you're second question, yes. The concept was conceived by someone which gave birth to the development and it's manifestation as we know it today and continue to see evolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what Midrash you’re reading.

On the one hand we have the Gemara, Shabbos 30b:

> דכתיב (קהלת א, ג) מה יתרון לאדם בכל עמלו שיעמול תחת השמש ואמרי דבי ר' ינאי תחת השמש הוא דאין לו קודם שמש יש לו
>
> As it’s written (Koheles 1:3): “What benefit is there to a person in all of his labor which he works under the sun?” And the academy of R’ Yannai said: “‘Under’ the sun is where he doesn’t have; ‘before’ the sun he has.”

As Rashi explains, this means that if one toils in Torah, which was created before the sun, he is exempt from this teaching of Koheles, and he will reap its rewards.

We see from here that “under the sun” excludes Torah; therefore, it’s logical to apply this to our verse, in 1:9, which says that there is nothing new “under the sun” - but Chiddushim are new.

Rashi, while not going on that particular exposition, says a similar thought on Koheles 1:9 itself:

> מַה שֶּׁהָיָה הוּא שֶׁיִּהְיֶה וְגוֹ'. בְּכָל־מַה שֶּׁהוּא לָמֵד בְּדָבָר שֶׁהוּא חֲלִיפֵי הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ, אֵין בּוֹ חִדּוּשׁ; לֹא יִרְאֶה אֶלָּא מָה שֶּׁהָיָה כְבָר, שֶׁנִּבְרָא בְשֵׁשֶׁת יְמֵי בְרֵאשִׁית. אֲבָל הַהוֹגֶה בַתּוֹרָה, מוֹצֵא בָהּ תָּמִיד חִדּוּשֵׁי טְעָמִים, כְּעִנְיָן שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר, "דַּדֶּיהָ יְרַוּוּךָ בְכָל־עֵת". מָה הַדַּד הַזֶּה, כָּל־זְמַן שֶׁהַתִּינוֹק מְמַשְׁמֵשׁ בּוֹ מוֹצֵא בוֹ טַעַם, אַף דִּבְרֵי תוֹרָה כֵּן. וְכֵן מָצִינוּ בְמַסֶּכֶת חֲגִיגָה, שֶׁאָמַר רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר בֶּן־הוֹרְקְנוֹס דְּבָרִים שֶׁלֹּא שְׁמָעָתַן אֹזֶן, בְּמַעֲשֵׂה מֶרְכָּבָה:
>
> “That which was is that which will be.” In whatever he learns, if it’s in exchange for the sun [i.e. for a livelihood], there is nothing new. He will only see that which was already, which was created during the six days of Creation. But one who speaks in Torah, he will find new flavors in it constantly. This is like that which is said, “Her breasts will feed you at all times.” Just as this breast, whenever the infant suckles on it, he finds flavor, so, too, are the words of Torah. So do we find in Maseches Chagigah, that R’ Eliezer Ben Hurkanis said things which nobody had previously heard regarding the Ma’aseh Merkavah.

That’s a very nice answer, but there’s an alternative one: the OP’s assumption is actually correct.

Says the Midrash in Koheles Rabbah (editions vary, but in mine it’s in 1:10):

> יֵשׁ דָּבָר שֶׁיֹּאמַר רְאֵה זֶה חָדָשׁ הוּא, כְּתִיב (דברים ט, י): וַיִּתֵּן ה' אֵלַי אֶת שְׁנֵי לוּחֹת הָאֲבָנִים כְּתֻבִים בְּאֶצְבַּע אֱלֹהִים וַעֲלֵיהֶם כְּכָל הַדְּבָרִים, אָמַר רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי, עֲלֵיהֶם, וַעֲלֵיהֶם, כָּל, כְּכָל, דְּבָרִים, הַדְּבָרִים, הַמִּצְוָה, כָּל הַמִּצְוָה, לְלַמֶּדְךָ שֶׁמִּקְרָא וּמִשְׁנָה הֲלָכוֹת תּוֹסֶפְתּוֹת וְהַגָּדוֹת וּמַה שֶּׁתַּלְמִיד וָתִיק עָתִיד לְהוֹרוֹת, כְּבָר הָיָה וְנִתַּן הֲלָכָה לְמשֶׁה מִסִּינַי, מִנַיִן, מִמַּה שֶּׁכָּתוּב יֵשׁ דָּבָר שֶׁיֹּאמַר רְאֵה זֶה דָּבָר חָדָשׁ הוּא, וַהֲרֵי חֲבֵרוֹ מוֹכִיחַ עָלָיו כְּבָר הָיָה לְעוֹלָם.
>
> “There will be a thing which you will say, ‘See, this is new!’” It is written (Devarim 9:10): “And Hashem gave to me the two stone tablets, written with the Finger of G-d, and upon them was like all the words [that were on the first ones].” Said R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi: “[Instead of] ‘On them’ [it says] ‘“and” on them.’ [Instead of] ‘all’ [it says] ‘“like” all.’ [Instead of] ‘words’ [it says] ‘“the” words.’ [Instead of] ‘the commandment’ [it says] ‘the “entire” commandment.’ This teaches you that Tanach, Mishnah, Halacha, Tosefta, Aggadah, **and that which a conscientious student will teach in the future - they already existed and were given to Moshe on Sinai.** How do I know this? From that which it says, ‘There is a thing which you will say, “See, this is new!”’ - and his friend will rebuke him, “‘It already was in the world!’”

So there’s two lines of thought. One is that, indeed, Chiddush is not such a Chiddush, and the other (which I’ve heard quoted much more often), that Chiddushim are actually exempt from “nothing is new under the sun.”

Comment: Mic drop! What a beautiful answer. Thank you.